# Шифр цезаря. Как убрать символы?

Tags: c++

Код цезаря. Если вбиваю слово "zozo", то выводит "}r}r". Как сделать цикл заново по алфавиту, чтобы символы не брались

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "RUS");

    char buff[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    cout << "Введите сообщение,которое будет закодированно" << endl;
    cin >> buff;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
        buff[i] += 3;
    cout << buff << endl;

    cout << "Decode: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
        buff[i] -= 3;
    cout << buff << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, зачем вы в `buff` изначально вбиваете весь алфавит?...

```
buff[i] += 3;
```

Например, так: заменим это на

```
if ((buff[i] += 3) > 'z') buff[i] -= 'z'-'a';
```

А при декодировании

```
if ((buff[i] -= 3) < 'a') buff[i] += 'z'-'a';
```

Примерно так. Но это годится только для символов в диапазоне `a-z`. Для более сложных, особенно составных, диапазонов лучше воспользоваться перекодировочной таблицей.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

А также вместо условий можно использовать арифметику по модулю:

```
int alphabet_sz = 'z'-'a' +1;

//Encode
buff[i] = (buff[i] - 'a' + 3 + alphabet_sz) % alphabet_sz + 'a';

//Decode
buff[i] = (buff[i] - 'a' - 3 + alphabet_sz) % alphabet_sz + 'a';
```